# Salesforce Custom label does not show value in the lwc control within Local Development environment

Tags: lightning-web-components

Js file:

```
import customlabel from '@salesforce/label/testLabel1';

export default class GetCustomLabels extends LightningElement {

    label = {

        customlabel,

    };   

}
```

HTML File:

```
<div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">

    <lightning-input 

            type="myLabel" 

            label={label.customlabel}

            value="">

    </lightning-input>       

</div>
```

When running the Local Development server, the result shows as below

[image]

It displays label name as `object([labelname])` . It does not show custom label value.

if i import with namespace as below

```
import customlabel from '@salesforce/label/***c.testLabel1';***
```

then it renders as `[c.testLabel1]`

What am i missing. Please help.

Referred the below :

https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/custom-labels-in-lightning-web-component-lwc/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this the exact component that you're seeing this error with? I just tried this in my org and it seems to be working for me.

Comment: I would change the declaration of `label` to `label: { customLabel: customLabel }`.

Comment: Thank you @Callum MacErlich for your response. This error i am seeing in VS Code after starting local development server. I have issue deploying to org. It's not allowing to deploy and unable to find exact error. VS code just says issue deploying to org and exit code 1.  However does it expected to work same way in local development server after connecting to Sandbox? Let me try to fix deployment issue and will try in the org.

Comment: @Phil W Thank you for your response. the label: {customLabel: customLabel} gives the syntax error.

Comment: I accidentally used a colon instead of equals: `label = { customLabel: customLabel };`.

Comment: I should probably clarify that I updated the reference for importing it to ```import customlabel from '@salesforce/label/c.testLabel1';``` otherwise I had an error deploying as well. If you have issues deploying but don't get an error back it's worth logging into your org and checking the deployment status page, it should have all of the errors that have been thrown when trying to deploy via VS Code.

Comment: Thank you once again @Callum MacErlich for your response. Yes you are right after adding "c.testLabel1" in the import it deployed to org and working as expected. That means it is showing the custom label value. Still have this question.......Why, it did not work in the VS Code local development server?  Should we expected that certain things does not work as org? or Am i missing any environment settings so that it should work as is like in Org? Appreciate your help once again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for clarifying that this is only related to the Local Development server, that has helped find what I believe to be the root cause of this for you.

The Local Development Server needs some additional setup to reference the Custom Labels that are available in your org.

In your folder structure, you should have a `localdevserver.config.json` file. Within this, you need to configure the path to your Custom Label folder like this: `"customLabelsFile": "labels/CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml"`

Hope this helps!